# Xamarin.UITest on physical device address already in use

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac, xamarin.uitest

Since I have problems running my Xamarin.UITest on the iOS Simulator I wanted to try to run it on a physical device. I can run the app from Visual Studio on the device correctly, but running the UITest fails. Unfortunatly I haven't found something about the error online yet.

```
SetUp : System.Exception : Unable to start portforwarding: ** Message: Probing for device(s)
** Message: Device found: cd70749db00bbf8db8c92d6214a5028ff3b9584d

** (process:35402): CRITICAL **: Unable to claim server port 27753: Error binding to address: Address already in use
```

I restarted the app and Visual Studio on Mac. The device is activated for UI Automation.

Comment: I start the app by `return ConfigureApp.iOS.InstalledApp("{appname}").StartApp();`

Answer (score 0):

After restarting the Mac the UITest started.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an iPhone

1. Assure you have the Test Cloud Agent NuGet package installed
2. Within your iOS project go to AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching() and add ->

   ```
   #if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD
   Xamarin.Calabash.Start();
   #endif
   ```
3. Also, add ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD to conditional compilation symbols for iOS project

For reference, check out Microsoft's documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/xamarin-forms) .

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message when trying to execute the Xamarin.UITests on a real iPhone while still having an iPhone Simulator running. After closing the iPhone Simulator the error was not shown any longer.